# Phone Number detection and calling

Tags: blackberry, detection, phone-number

i am developing the BlackBerry app in which the data comes from the web services.The data contains the **phone numbers** of the different countries and also there is **call functionality** in the app.
I have used **ActiveRichTextField** to display data in labelfield so that phone numbers and email id's can be detected.It also detects the numbers and mail id's but it fails to detect some of the numbers.Do any body know how to detect number such as **+618 12345678/79** and sort of the data.Any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to recognise the strings? Or to receive the call?

Comment: I want to recognize mobile/telephone number and email id's from string which i get response from web service and to call/mail on particular number.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to recognise a string in another given string, you want to look at `PatternRepository`. This is a system managed collection of strings, that is used to add context menus to given strings.

If your string is found on the device, it will show the menu that you define. So you need to subclass `ApplicationMenuItem` and provide your own `run()` method.

The following code will set up your device to recognise a regular expression, and create a context menu item for when that pattern is found:

```
    // MyAppMenuItem extends ApplicationMenuItem
    MyAppMenuItem appMenuItem = new MyAppMenuItem(0);
    ApplicationMenuItem[] applicationMenu = new ApplicationMenuItem[1];
    applicationMenu[0] = appMenuItem;

    // register the pattern to identify the phone number
    PatternRepository.addPattern(
        ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor(),
        "*** REGEXP String to recognise phone numbers ***", 
        PatternRepository.PATTERN_TYPE_REGULAR_EXPRESSION,
        applicationMenu);
```

I found that this does not work in HTML fields ([BlackBerry - intercept text in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500415/blackberry-intercept-text-in-html)). But it worked in almost all other places across my app, and in other apps, like email. If you only want it to work in your app, you can deregister this pattern when your app exits.

Note that you can add many different patterns to the `PatternRepository` - one for each style of number or email address that you want to recognise.